# Extract dynamic key from JsonPath

Tags: java, json

```
{
"random": {
   "5756cd7a-4662-4428-9b09-dbff3080450a": {
       "@class": "one",
       "id": "5756cd7a-4662-4428-9b09-dbff3080450a"
   },
   "857ef5ee-af98-4f24-89fe-29bdbebde882": {
       "@class": "two",
       "id": "857ef5ee-af98-4f24-89fe-29bdbebde882"
   }
 }
}
```

This is my api 'response' which is in type JsonPath.

```
String random = response.getString("random");
```

I'm stuck after this as to how to extract the first random element.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation, perhaps you could use [`JsonPath#getMap`](http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.1/apidocs/com/jayway/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html#getMap%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%29) to do the extraction, e.g.:

```
final Map<String, RandomObject> result = response.getMap("random", String.class, RandomObject.class);
```

Where `RandomObject` would be something like:

```
public class RandomObject {
    private String klass; // N.B. Not sure how to deal with @class naming
    private String id;

    // ... constructor/setters/getters etc...
}
```

Although, I'm not very familiar with this `JsonPath` library, so it may not be that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your json response as string in responseJsonString, the code below may solve your problem.

```
    List<String> randomIDS = JsonPath.read(responseJsonString, "$.random..id");
    Collections.reverse(randomIDS);

    for (String randomID : randomIDS) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("$.random.");
        String randomClass = JsonPath.read(
                responseJsonString, 
                stringBuilder.append(randomID).append(".@class").toString());
        System.out.println(randomClass);
    }
```